# What does this converge to?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, convergence-divergence, summation

Consider the sum of the reciprocals of all numbers of the form $p^n$ with $n ≥ 2$ and $p$ prime, this is shown to converge by noting that it is strictly less then this convergent sum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power.

Does anyone know what this sum is or where I can find information?

Comment: Surely there is no closed form for it. If you can calculate it to a few decimal places, you can type it into the internet and see what comes up.

Comment: You are looking for $P(n)$, where $P$ is the prime zeta function. I can't find any closed values, but this article is interesting http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html

Comment: @ElliotG it's the sum of p (n) from n >1

Comment: an aproximation http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%5Bsum+%5B1%2FPrime+%5Bn%5D%5Ek%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C200%7D%5D%2C+%7Bk%2C2%2C50%7D%5D&x=0&y=0 .773056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a closed form for it. As others mentioned in comments, there's a connection with the prime zeta function:
$$S=\sum_{p\,prime}\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac1{p^n}=\sum_{p\,prime}\frac1{p(p-1)}=\sum^\infty_{n=2}P(n),$$ and we can calculate the prime zeta function easily through $$P(s)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\,\ln\zeta(ns),$$ where $\mu$ is Moebius function. Obviously, $P(n)=O(2^{-n}),$ so the series converges rapidly. We can use that to get a better numerical value, but we can also substitute the expression for $P(n)$ and change the order of summation:
$$S=\sum^\infty_{m=2}\left(\sum_{n|m, n<m}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\right)\,\ln\zeta(m).$$
Now we know that $$\sum_{n|m}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}=\frac{\varphi(m)}{m},$$  where $\varphi$ is the totient function, but the terms with $m=n$ are missing, because $P(1)$ is missing in our sum, for obvious reasons. So we finally have the curious result
$$S=\sum^\infty_{m=2}\frac{\varphi(m)-\mu(m)}{m}\,\ln\zeta(m).$$ As was to be expected, both formulas give the same numerical approximation, $S=0.7731566690497961$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A136141